Firebase function HTTP request returns 429 Too many request error
I have an app where I use firebase as a backend. I have two gen1 firebase function, the first downloads a file and save it to firebase storage as a json file. My second function is a HTTP endpoint what downloads this file from storage and response with the json file.
It worked perfectly until I had too much user with too much request. In google cloud log I can see only this message, what is not so informative:
{
insertId: "16qoz24f6z01ka"
labels: {
execution_id: "gm3e668c9lxj"
runtime_version: "nodejs20_20240421_20_12_1_RC00"
}
logName: "projects/currency-converter-1d6e8/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-05-03T08:37:34.877763494Z"
resource: {
labels: {
function_name: "premiumapi"
project_id: "currency-converter-1d6e8"
region: "us-central1"
}
type: "cloud_function"
}
severity: "DEBUG"
textPayload: "Function execution took 5 ms, finished with status code: 429"
timestamp: "2024-05-03T08:37:34.569502107Z"
trace: "projects/currency-converter-1d6e8/traces/a541c12b1432ac4067ec5cdd1ad10a90"

This is my code:
export const premiumapi = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
  })
  .https.onRequest(premiumGetLatestPricesFromStorage);

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 1000, // 1 minute
  max: 5, // limit each IP to 10 requests per windowMs
});

export const premiumGetLatestPricesFromStorage = express()
  .get(`/${apiVersion}/rates`, limiter, (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    downloadFromStorageAndDecodeJsonData(path.latestPriceStoragePath)
      .then((Result) => {
        if (Result.success === false) {
          // Send (500) Internal Server Error
          functions.logger.error(`❌ [ERROR HTTP GET REQUEST] Couldn't get latest prices from Storage, error: ${Result.log}`);
          response.status(500).send("Rates not available!");
        } else {
          // Send the JSON data
          latestPrices = Result.data;
          response.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
          response.status(200).json(latestPrices);
          functions.logger.log(`✅ [SUCCESSFULLY GET HTTP REQUEST] ${Result.log}`);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        functions.logger.error(`❌ [ERROR HTTP GET REQUEST] error: ${error}`);
        response.status(500).send("Rates not available!");
      });
  });

export async function downloadFromStorageAndDecodeJsonData(storagePath: string): Promise<Result> {
  try {
    const file = bucket.file(storagePath);
    const fileBuffer = await file.download();
    const fileContents = fileBuffer[0].toString();
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileContents);
    return {success: true, data: jsonData, log: `✅ [SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED AND PARSED DATA FROM STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}`};
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(`❌ [ERROR DOWNLOADING DATA FROM STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}, error: ${error}`);
    return {success: false, log: `❌ [ERROR DOWNLOADING DATA FROM STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}, error: ${error}`};
  }
}

export async function encodeJsonDataAndUploadToStorage(storagePath: string, downloadedData: any): Promise<Result> {
  try {
    const file = bucket.file(storagePath);
    const jsonEncodedData = JSON.stringify(downloadedData, null, 4);
    await file.save(jsonEncodedData, {
      metadata: {
        contentType: "application/json",
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=10",
      },
    });
    return {success: true, log: `✅ [SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED TO STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}`};
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(`❌ [ERROR UPLOADING TO STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}, error: ${error}`);
    return {success: false, log: `❌ [ERROR UPLOADING TO STORAGE] path: ${storagePath}, error: ${error}`};
  }
}

When the request successfully returns with 200, I can see my log message in google cloud log.
Anyone has any suggestion how to decide if it is a storage limitation problem or http request limitation on what else?
How could I debug a little bit more detailed?
I tried to set cacheControl of the file in the storage to "public, max-age=10", but no change.
